# SQL the column's next one doesn't contain

Tags: sql

```
SQL_TABLE

ID  | Index | Name
____| _____ |_____________
1   | 13    | House_floor
2   | 13    | Room_number1
3   | 7     | Bed_Number1
4   | 7     | Gym
5   | 13    | House_roof
6   | 4     | Room_number2
7   | 7     | Bed_LivingRoom
8   | 23    | Gym
```

How do I write conditions to express that
WHERE excludes index 7 which are contains underline "_"

so the output look like below

```
ID  | Index | Name
____| _____ |_____________
1   | 13    | House_floor
2   | 13    | Room_number1
4   | 7     | Gym
5   | 13    | House_roof
6   | 4     | Room_number2
8   | 23    | Gym
```

the condition I wrote doesn't give me what I want

```
SELECT * 
FROM SQL_TABLE
WHERE Index != 7 AND NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(Name, '_')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use `LIKE` for string comparison and escape `_` in your search pattern:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SQL_TABLE
WHERE
    (Index = 7 AND Name NOT LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\')
    OR Index <> 7;
```

The condition for not containing `_` should only apply to rows with `Index = 7`, so you add an `OR` condition to include `Index <> 7`.

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL uses `LIKE`.  The underscore character is a special character, but `LIKE` supports the `ESCAPE` option.  You can do something like:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM SQL_TABLE t
WHERE Index <> 7 AND NAME NOT LIKE '%$_%' ESCAPE '$';
```

The default is `'\'`, so you can do:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM SQL_TABLE t
WHERE Index <> 7 AND NAME NOT LIKE '%\_%';
```

Note that `<>` is traditionally the standard operator for not equals.